# Turtlebot Source Installation and cakin_make error

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am the new user in ubuntu 14.04 and ros-indigo,i dont have any ideal how to solve it
When I want to install the Indigo version of the Turtlebot package from source using the instructions here:
[link text](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation)

When I run this step:`rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y` in ~/rocon it failed

i see the similar in ROS Answers so i follow and  try to  run`rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y -r`again,but i got

```
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-indigo-turtlebot-gazebo] failed
apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-indigo-turtlebot-gazebo]
```

i try to ignore that and go next step   `catkin_make` and it is successful

i run this step:`rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y` in ~/kobuki,it  failed again

```
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-indigo-ar-track-alvar] failed
apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-indigo-ar-track-alvar]
```

i used catkin_make and it is successful  too

finally, i run this step:`rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y` in~/turtlebot ,it  failed and got error at catkin_make too

`rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y` error

```
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-indigo-pcl-ros] failed
apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-indigo-navigation] failed
apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-indigo-dwa-local-planner] failed
apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-indigo-move-base] failed
apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-indigo-pcl-ros]
apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-indigo-navigation]
apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-indigo-dwa-local-planner]
apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-indigo-move-base]
```

`catkin_make` error

```
enter code here
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pcl_ros" with any
of the following names:

pcl_rosConfig.cmake
pcl_ros-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "pcl_ros" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"pcl_ros_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"pcl_ros" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_follower/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/joe/turtlebot/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/joe/turtlebot/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

how could i solve this error problems?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221559/turtlebot-source-installation-and-cakin_make-error/) by [peterlin300](https://answers.ros.org/users/25026/peterlin300/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peterlin300](https://answers.ros.org/users/25026/peterlin300/) on 2015-12-07**:
OH! i will try it again!!
in this two week, i'm prepare my midterm exam and try to run it with the system which is attach with turtlebot2.
when i run `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color`
it shows [rospack] couldn't find package [image_view]  whats error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you able to complete the step "2.3.1 Preparation" on that page?  Also what platform are you running ubuntu on? To help you more we need to know more about what you've done to setup your computer to try to reproduce your problem.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0